# node & websockets, multiple eventListeners results in MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, websocket, event-listener

i have an app that uses a websocket connection to send some data to the front-end after a page has been loaded. I use the **locals** variable of express to pass the websocket server to the router.

**This is the socket setup:**

```
//certificate
var key = fs.readFileSync('encryption/cert.key');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('encryption/cert.pem');
var options = { key: key, cert: cert, passphrase: 'kevinius', requestCert: false, rejectUnauthorized: false };

//create server
const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, (err)=>{
    console.log(`Listening on: https://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`)
});

// websocket
let wss = new WebSocket({ server });
app.locals.socket = wss;
```

**The router setup:**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

var socket = req.app.locals.socket;

console.log('yesssssss')
        socket.on('connection', (ws) => {
            //this keeps on adding new eventListeners resulting in MaxListenersExceededWarning
            console.log('connection');
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(['cover', htmlTemplate]), (err) => { 
                // 
            });
        })

}
```

**However, this results in multiple eventListeners being added on each new page refresh**:

```
yesssssss
connection
yesssssss
connection
connection
yesssssss
connection
connection
connection
```

**Eventually leading to this error:**:

```
(node:15515) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

> So what's missing in my setup? Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved it... seems i didn't understand websockets conceptually.

In the router i removed all websocket related code and created a module that gets called only once on server startup.

**server.js**:

```
const sockLib = require('./library/ws.js');
sockLib.setConnection(server);
```

**library/ws.js**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws').Server;

var wss;
var socket;

function setConnection(server) {
    wss = new WebSocket({ server });
    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {

        socket = ws;

        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            let mss = JSON.parse(message);
            if (mss[0] == 'home/covers') {
                callYourOtherCode(mss[1]);
            }
        });

    })
}

module.exports.setConnection = setConnection;
```

Comment: Just a side note: Google App Engine (Node) Standard doesn't support websockets so i opted for XMLHttpRequest instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest